# Actionscript 3: Port forwarding

Tags: actionscript-3, tcp, port

Is it possible to do port forwarding in actionscript3??

I'm doing a simple messenger in as3 and it works fine in LAN, but doesn't work over the internet since the computers usually behind NAT gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem in flash. This is a problem in your config of network.
Flash work fine event if using port forwarding.